# 'Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml.' error with code that works on another computer

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Native xml interpretor is not found, but only on one computer

I have installed and reinstalled python multiple times

```
import xml

with open('example.xml', 'r') as f:
    xml_content = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_content, 'xml')
```

And get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gregg\OneDrive - Gregg Lund, DO, MS, FAAP\Python\PubMedScript\TestXML.py", line 7, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_content, 'xml')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gregg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 250, in __init__
    raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Since it works on one computer I dont know why it does not work on the other computer

Comment: Apparently the other computer has a library installed that can parse xml, but this computer does not.

Comment: John - Thank you for the editing. But since the XML parser is part of the python install, why wouln'd be installed? How do I check?.

Comment: _But since the XML parser is part of the python install_ You're not using the built-in xml parser -- you're using BeautifulSoup.  `import xml` is never used.

Comment: John - The code below is an exact copy of the real code that I have used on the other computer that works.               'i_esearch_ids = [i.text for i in BeautifulSoup(esearch_request.text,'xml').find_all('Id')]'

Comment: How do I check to see if XML is installed?

Comment: when I run the following code from cmd I do not get an error     python -c "import xml"

Comment: Yes, of course `xml` is installed, because it is built-in.  But BeautifulSoup does not (apparently) use the standard `xml` package to do its parsing -- it uses some other third-party library.  Whatever that third-party library is, one of your computers has it and the other one doesn't.

Comment: You can run `pip list` on both computers to see what optional libraries are installed.  Hopefully some library on that list will have some obvious name related to xml parsing.

Comment: John - I will try and see wether the 'pip list' on the two are different when I get home next week